# on delete can't get my root directory path

Tags: php, laravel

I am getting wrong path on delete action. my forum directory

path is `//localhost/laravel/public/forum`  .and on light box the
delete button making path is `//localhost/forum/group/2/delete`  . but i want this path is like

```
//localhost/laravel/public/forum/group/5/delete  ..
```

here is app.js code

```
$('.delete_group').click(function(event)    {
        $('#btn_delete_group').prop('href', '/forum/group/' +
event.target.id + '/delete');   });
```

and button is

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary"
id="btn_delete_group">Delete</a>
```

when i move the cursor on this delete button it shows

```
//localhost/forum/group/2/delete
```

Comment: You've got `/` at the start of your new href, which means it's a local-absolute url. perhaps you want `'/laravel/public/forum/group/' + ...` instead.

Comment: Thanks Marc B.. its working good now :)

Comment: actually i'm following a video tutorial. and in tutorial they doing same in prop('href','/forum/...') and there this path is working good but not in my side.